# Prove :$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin n}{n!}>\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos n}{n!}$

Tags: real-analysis, summation

How can we prove that :

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin n}{n!}>\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos n}
{n!}$$

The only difference between the two seems of the trigonometric function sine and cosine.

So, it seems like there are more numbers $i\in \mathbb N$ for which $$\sin i>\cos i$$ and vice-versa.

However, I am unsure of how to proceed for a proof of this. Other ideas to solve are welcome also.

Comment: The $n!$ gets large quickly, so you can find the difference in partial sums for the first few  terms and then show it is impossible to close the gap in the tail

Comment: Expansion on Henry comment:

$$\tfrac{8}{3}-e = \sum_{n = 4}^\infty \frac{-1}{n!} \le \sum_{n = 4}^\infty \frac{\sin n}{n!} \le \sum_{n = 4}^\infty\frac{1}{n!} = e - \tfrac{8}{3}$$
and likewise
$$\tfrac{8}{3}-e  \le \sum_{n = 4}^\infty \frac{\cos n}{n!} \le  e - \tfrac{8}{3}$$
so the difference satisfies:
$$\left | \sum_{n = 4}^\infty \frac{\sin n}{n!} - \sum_{n = 4}^\infty \frac{\cos n}{n!} \right| \le 2e - \tfrac{16}{3} \le 0.11$$

Now simply note $$\sum_{n=0}^{3}\frac{\cos\left(n\right)}{n!}+0.11 < 1.3 < \sum_{n=0}^{3}\frac{\sin\left(n\right)}{n!}$$

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Notice that
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\cos n}{n!} &= \text{Re}\bigg(\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{e^{in}}{n!}\bigg) \\
\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\sin n}{n!} &= \text{Im}\bigg(\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{e^{in}}{n!}\bigg)
\end{align*}
The summation on the right hand side can be computed explicitly, as it is a special case of the Maclaurin series for the exponential function: $$\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{e^{in}}{n!} = e^{e^i} = e^{\cos(1) + i\sin(1)} = e^{\cos(1)}\big(\cos(\sin 1) + i \sin(\sin 1)\big)$$ Hence, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\cos n}{n!} &= e^{\cos 1}\cos(\sin 1) \\
\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{\sin n}{n!} &= e^{\cos 1}\sin(\sin 1)
\end{align*}
Thus, you just need to show that $\sin(\sin 1) > \cos(\sin 1)$. Notice that $\sin x > \cos x$ for all $x$ in the interval $(\pi/4,\pi/2]$, and $\sin(1)\in (\pi/4,\pi/2]$.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align} & \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin n}{n!} - \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos n}{n!}  \\ \ge &\sum\limits_{n=0}^3 \frac{\sin n - \cos n}{n!} - 2\sum\limits_{n=4}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} 
\\  \gt & \;0.1524-0.1033 \\ \gt &\;0\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the short answer. Though the second last step would involve a calculator.

Comment: @An_Elephant - yes, for $n=0,1,2,3$ while the remaining infinite sum is $2(e-1-1-\frac12-\frac16)$.  So not much use of a calculator.

Comment: Using a calculator also reveals that your $\sin n > \cos n$ point only matters for $n=1,2,3$ giving gaps big enough to offset $\sin 0 < \cos 0$ and the worst imaginable case for anything that might possibly happen for larger $n$